# What kind of data structure should be used for working with dynamic sets where elements follow "normal distribution" and why?

Tags: data-structures, hash-tables

I am wondering if Hash tables would be a good choice as it mentions dynamic sets to store data which follows normal distribution.
I have doubt in this because normal distribution has bell shaped curve which means elements near the median are more than others. So, If I use hash table then that would lead to clustering.

So, any insights regarding this would be helpful.

Edit: Common operations on a dynamic set are Find,Insert, Delete, and also
analysing what are the complexities for each operation.

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information to provide useful answers.  Please [edit] the question to tell us what operations you want the data structure to provide, what your requirements are, and what approaches you've considered and your analysis of them.  You say "it mentions"; what mentions that?  If you're referring to some source, please cite the source and summarize what it says.

Comment: I aint referring to any other source. And the question "itself mentions" dynamic set.
And the basic operations on dynamic sets are like Find, Insert, Delete operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hash function might not map the nearby elements to the same bucket. For example suppose the hash function is $h(x) = x^2 \mod p$ where $p$ is some prime number say $97$. Suppose $x$ follows normal distribution with values between $1$ to $1000$. And, suppose that most of the values are concentrated around $500$.
If you compute the hash values at $x = 499$, $x = 500$, and $x = 501$,
the hash function gives the following values: $h(499) = 2$, $h(500) = 31$, and $h(501) = 62$. Note that, although the input values are close to each other, their mapped values are not close to each other and they lie in completely different buckets.

Designing a good hash function that uniformly maps the values across the table, mostly depends on a particular use case. But, you can always make your hash function more complex by adding more terms to it, for example, by adding more terms of the form $x^k$ to it, etc. It will hopefully provide a uniform spread of values across the table.

Comment: It cleared my doubt. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

A 64 bit hash for 64 bit Floating-point numbers will more or less be just the bit pattern of the number; “more or less” because you need to handle +0 and -0, and you have to decide how to handle NaNs.

The index of a slot in the hash table is that hash, modulo the table size, which is likely a prime number. That index will be practically random; whether your Floating-point numbers have some distribution  is not going to make any difference.

Comment: Ok. I also want to know that  if the knowledge of the distribution of data can help us in choosing hash functions which guarantees uniform distribution of data in hash table.

Comment: Never seen any example of that. You have a 52 bit mantissa, and many of the bits are not affected by the distribution, and that’s enough to create a good hash.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.